# Why don't SE staff write their full email in their bio?

Tags: support, profile-page, community-managers

I noticed that SE staff do not write their full email in their bio.

Example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat):

> If there's anything you think I could help you with, you can reach me at stackoverflow.com: jnat@...

And [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija):

> As you might expect, my email starts with `Catija` and ends with `stackexchange.com`. If you have a good recipe for cake... or community building, please reach out.

Since emails aren't blocked in a bio, why do they do this?

Comment: The only thing wrong I could find with this question was the [tag:email] tag, which according to its description is for questions about e-mails SE/SO sends to people, not e-mail adresses in community manager's profiles... So I've changed that :)

Comment: While I don't work here, I did that for a week. I got some guy asking me for free forensics help. They'll get deluged with garbage.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because they don't want to attract spam emails from companies using email scrapers.

The Wikipedia page on [Email-address harvesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email-address_harvesting) explains:

> Email harvesting is the process of obtaining lists of email addresses using various methods. Typically these are then used for bulk email or spam.

Answer (score 16):

## To prevent automatic crawlers

Having your e-Mail address on your bio is a surefire way to get on a lot of spam lists very quickly.

Of course, writing it down like this isn't going to stop a determined spammer, but it keeps the bots away that look for a construct like `<something>@<something>.<something>` and report it as e-Mail address.